# jquery animations choppy after using css3 transitions

Tags: jquery

The animations work fine at first, but another function uses the css3 transition property to animate a "rotate" and after this runs, the animations become really choppy.

Here are the two functions that become choppy:

```
function fadePlayer(){
        $(".logof, .location").fadeOut(2000);
        $(".turntable, .arm, .bio, .controls").fadeIn(2000);
        $(".logor").animate({
            backgroundSize: "104px 103px",
            height: "103px",
            width: "104px",
            top: "5px",
            left: "33px"
        }, 1000);   
    }
```

and

```
function unFadePlayer(){
        $(".logof, .location").fadeIn(500);
        $(".turntable, .arm, .bio, .controls").fadeOut(500, function(){

        });
        $(".logor").animate({
            backgroundSize: "49px 49px",
            height: "49px",
            width: "49px",
            top: "23px",
            left: "63px"
        }, 250);    
    }
```

And the transition affects are called like so:

```
playing: function(){
            var degree = 0;
            spinAction = setInterval(function(){
                degree = degree < 5 ? degree + 5 : 0; 
                $(".logor").css({
                    '-webkit-transition':'all 1s ease-in-out',
                    '-webkit-transform':'rotate('+degree+'deg)',
                    '-ms-transition':'all 1s ease-in-out',
                    '-ms-transform':'rotate('+degree+'deg)',
                    '-moz-transition':'all 1s ease-in-out',
                    '-moz-transform':'rotate('+degree+'deg)',
                    '-o-transition':'all 1s ease-in-out',
                    '-o-transform':'rotate('+degree+'deg)',
                    'transition':'all 1s ease-in-out',
                    'transform':'rotate('+degree+'deg)',
                });
            }, 1000);
            var angle = 0;
            wobbleAction = setInterval(function(){
                angle = angle < 2 ? angle + 2 : 0; 
                $(".arm").css({
                    '-webkit-transform-origin':'14 14', 
                    '-webkit-transition':'all 1s ease-in-out',
                    '-webkit-transform':'rotate('+angle+'deg)',
                    '-ms-transform-origin':'14 14', 
                    '-ms-transition':'all 1s ease-in-out',
                    '-ms-transform':'rotate('+angle+'deg)',
                    '-moz-transform-origin':'14 14', 
                    '-moz-transition':'all 1s ease-in-out',
                    '-moz-transform':'rotate('+angle+'deg)',
                    '-o-transform-origin':'14 14', 
                    '-o-transition':'all 1s ease-in-out',
                    '-o-transform':'rotate('+angle+'deg)',
                    'transform-origin':'14 14', 
                    'transition':'all 1s ease-in-out',
                    'transform':'rotate('+angle+'deg)',
                });
            }, 1000);   

        },
        pause: function(){
            clearInterval(spinAction);
            clearInterval(wobbleAction);
        },
```

"playing" and "pause" are just methods that respond to events.

The animation of backgroundSize is provided through a plug-in, but even with that taken out, each action happens with noticeable lag.  The fadeIn/Out stops fading the selected elements in unison, and each line of the animation happens in subsequent intervals, rather than all at once.

Any idea what could cause this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this [jquery plugin](https://github.com/heygrady/transform/wiki) to substitute for the transitions 
resolves the choppiness