# background-size cover makes css3 animation choppy

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have a grid of images that i want to animate to the top with css3. It works until i put Background-size: cover onto the grid. The animation becomes choppy. What am i doing wrong, or what can i do to prevent this?

When i use jquery's animation function it becomes even worse.

I also found something like:
-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
but this does not do the trick.

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/PqdVZ/

```
body{
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #ccc;
}

div.container.animate{
    top:-100%;
}
div.container{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: top 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: top 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: top 1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: top 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: top 1s ease-in-out;

}

ul{
   display: block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

li{
    width: 25%;;
    float: left;
    height: 160px;
    background-size: cover;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: What computer are you using? And in what browser have you tested it? It might be a computer performance issue. For me it works pretty well, but i have a powerful machine. Look over this too : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8600635/jquery-animations-choppy-after-using-css3-transitions

Comment: I have a very powerfull computer, and i use chrome. I do see that the example is smoother then the actual website. maybe because the real website is fullscreen. But i do see difference when i remove the background-size rule.

Comment: I still think there is a performance issue. The animation will relocate every single pixel from every image. So that will be a bit heavy for the browser to render, not to mention that the images are big if you say that the original variant is fullscreen. See this question too maybe it helps (follows the performance issue) . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7866423/css3-animations-and-performance-are-there-any-benchmarks .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your javascript, the problems lays in the CSS. Animating top, right, bottom and left is hardware accelerated. This is bad because it will run on your CPU and not on your GPU. When you see a jerky transition then you can bet that you are not hardware accelerating. So instead you should use hardware acceleration.

Instead of animating the top, you should animate the transform(x, y, z). This will will make it hardware accelerated.

So you have to change the following css:

```
div.container.animate{
    top:-100%;
}

div.container{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: top 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: top 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: top 1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: top 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: top 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

Into this:

```
div.container{
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0%, 0);
       -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0%, 0);
        -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0%, 0);
         -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0%, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, 0%, 0);

    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
       -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
         -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
            transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

div.container.animate{
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
       -moz-transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
        -ms-transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
         -o-transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
}
```

Here is the live link: http://jsfiddle.net/PqdVZ/1/